# Overleaf and .lco file

Tags: koma-script, overleaf, scrlttr2

I would like to edit a `.lco` file (for `scrlttr2`) in overleaf but it won’t open because this file type is not supported. So I have to download it and edit it in a text editor and then upload it again. This workaround is suitable when I work with a PC but not when I’m working with the iPad. Changing the extension into `.TEX` does not work either (now I can see the content but can’t edit it).

How can I edit `.lco` files in overleaf directly?

Comment: Sorry, this is a question only the overleaf support can solve! Please ask the overleaf support for this, it is off topic here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also addressed the question to the overleaf support team and quickly got an answer (thanks to Paul Gessler). Maybe it’s of interest for someone:

„Unfortunately changing the extension won't work: a file's editability is determined by its extension at upload time. It doesn't become editable if you change the file's extension once it's been uploaded.

But that actually enables a workaround for your case: If you upload the file as a `.tex` file initially, then it will be marked as editable, and you can change the extension to `.lco` once it's in Overleaf. Then the `.lco` file can be edited in Overleaf. Sorry about this inconvenience, but that will at least allow you to edit these files for the time being.“